# Strange behaviour jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen this in some topics but haven't fixed my script.

I have a piece of jQuery that doesn't work because of I use it to manage (validate ) a piece of html (form ) that is loaded using a jQuery function load() after loading the page.

But if I put for example an `alert("Something")` in the script outside the functions, it works.

I've tried putting the validation script inside these beginnings but it doesn't work...

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
$(document).ready(function () {
```

it is very strange... do have you a solution?

Update: working now, check the first answer's solution!

Comment: Without knowing what you're actually doing it's impossible to help.

Comment: Kolink understood and his tip worked, next time I'll try to add the code and explain myself better, tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to attach an event to an AJAX-loaded form, and it's not working because you're actually attaching it before the form exists.

Presumably you have `.load(url)` somewhere in there, so you should do this:

```
$("selector").load(url,"",function() {
    // do stuff to the loaded content, such as attaching events, here
});
```

Comment: Perfect understanding, that did the trick, thank you very much!